# What is the best way to scale UVs to fit an image?

Tags: texturing, uv

I was just wondering as it's something I often find myself doing, but is there a automated way to scale selected UVs to fit to the edges of the image boundary in the UV editor?

Currently I have a process which isn't too time consuming, but nonetheless a little bit more so than hitting a button. These images show my process and what I am trying to achieve.

[image: 1. Calculate scale value]
[image: 2. Apply scale and realign]

Note: that I scaled everything by the same value, but if I wanted to fit the image square, I would have to do this process once for width and again for height.

Is there a built-in function to do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Grab to corner + Scale (not preserving proprtions)

With the **Rotation/Scaling Pivot** set to **2D Cursor** and the cursor in the origin (0,0), activate the **Constraint to Image Bounds** option, grab the island in the corner and then scale:

[image]

---

### Pack island+Scale (preserving proportions)

As stated by the [Blender Reference Manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/uv_image/layout_editing.html#packing-islands):

> The Pack Islands tool, shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, will uniformly scale, then individually transform each Island so that they fill up the UV space as much as possible.

[image]

You can select multiple UV island to scale them while maintaining their relative proportions, or even just one as in the example to quickly scale every possible previusly unwrapped island to the bounds being sure it will not be stretched.

Notice that the box in the toolshelf is unchecked to prevent island's rotation.

Comment: Awesome! I'd seen the projection using bounds in other answers on BSE, but I didn't know about constrain to image bounds. I didn't realise pack islands would work individually either. My way seems really stupid now :) Thanks!

Comment: Option 1 still works in Blender 2.91.0 but the UI looks different, in "UV Editing" mode: 1. The "Rotation/Scaling Pivot" option is hidden behind a symbol that's directly below the menu bar with the "UV Editing" tab and that looks like a crosshair (fat dot in the middle with an outer ring and 4 lines touching it). 2. "Constrain to Image Bounds" can be found in the "UV" menu (another bar down). Alternative: With the UVs selected, hold down shift after pressing "g" ("grab") or "s" ("scale") while moving the mouse to snap to the grid of the image.

Answer (score 9):

When unwrapping you can use **Project from view (Bounds)** to fit the UVs using the full image on the UV editor.

[image]

Or you can edit the UVs using the **Constrain to image bounds** option:

[image]

Comment: +1, I had to unwrap something from top view but it was a pain to scale it to match the bounds, glad I found this before I inflicted too much brain damage to myself

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>U</kbd> > **Project from view (Bounds)**

In the Tool Shelf (<kbd>N</kbd>) or <kbd>F6</kbd>, check **Scale to Bounds**

In Blender 3.2, adjust the unwrap settings in the Adjust Last Operation (<kbd>F9</kbd>).

[image]

[image]

For further information see the [Blender Manual](http://www.blender.org/manual/editors/uv_image/unwrapping.html?highlight=unwrap#basic-mapping)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not quite what I'm looking for, since my object is complex and I arranged the UVs in a grid using the follow quads option.