# Can you auto-pack a selected group of islands in UV view?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I'm trying to figure out ways of optimizing my UV Layout creation workflow. Here's what I do so far:

1. mark seams on the mesh
2. select the mesh and press <kbd>u</kbd> <kbd>u</kbd> to auto unwrap it
3. if the UVMap image ("checkers" view) looks too distorted on the mesh, go back to step 1 (mark more seams).
4. Once satisfied, select the logical parts of the mesh in 3D View so only those corresponding islands show in the UV view. **Due to auto-unwrap, these islands are dispersed throughout the UV layout.**
5. Move each of these islands one-by-one close to each other so they are all in the same location in the UV layout
6. Repeat steps 5/6 for every part of the mesh

Is there an easier way to do step 5? Like some kind of command in UV mode like "auto-pack the selected islands" using the same underlying layout algorithm used for the initial unwrapping?

Also, if there are any tricks worth knowing that could speed up this process, please let me know! Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what is "dispersed throughout UV layout".. but you can pack selected islands by `Ctrl`+`P`. Also it's not clear whether you want to stack islands on top of each other or to place them next to each other.

Comment: Ah yes, `ctrl+p` was exactly what I was looking for, thanks for that! By "dispersed throughout" I meant that when you first unwrap the entire mesh and blender places all pieces arbitrarily in the UV layout. Leave an answer with the `Pack Islands` command and I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39580/what-is-the-best-way-to-scale-uvs-to-fit-an-image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [*Pack Islands*](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/uv_image/uv_editing/layout_editing.html#pack-islands) command to automatically organize all your islands so that they fill the UV space:

> The *Pack Islands* tool will uniformly scale, then individually transform each Island so that they fill up the UV space as much as possible.

[image: screenshot of pack islands]