# Scale down UV map to image bounds?

Tags: modeling

I have a really huge UV map somewhere in my UV image editor, is there a key shortcut to scale it down and position it within the image?

Using scale and grab takes forever.

Comment: You could press S to scale, then type in 0.08 or another really small number.

Comment: that won't center it, or at least put it in the bounds

Comment: Think this might help you: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39580/what-is-the-best-way-to-scale-uvs-to-fit-an-image